# create a refund online in magento2

Tags: magento2, refund

How to create a refund with online in magento 2. I created the creditmemo but the transactions details are not showing in the transaction list. Please guide me, how to do it?

Comment: There is only this way enable you to refund online: use extension please

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/136516)